# using jsf or richfaces to load the contents of a link in a tab

Tags: html, url, jsf, richfaces, richfaces-modal

I have a jsf tabbed page. how can i load a link within the tab to implement the functionality similar to page frames in html. I want to know both options as in jsf and richfaces.

Comment: all i want is to load the result page in the same tab panel in jsf.

Answer (score 0):

You can load another page inside the tab by using `<ui:include` tag.

**xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets**

> `<rich:tabPanel>`
>           `<rich:tab>`
>                 `<ui:include src="/result_page.xhtml" />`
>           `</rich:tab>`
>     `</rich:tabPanel>`